# How to bind XML to a page in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have some XML like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <People>
      <Person id="1">
        <Name>
          <FirstName>Manoj</FirstName>
          <LastName>Syamala</LastName>
        </Name>
      </Person>
      <Person id="2">
        <Name>
          <FirstName>Anthony</FirstName>
          <LastName>Roberts</LastName>
        </Name>
      </Person>
   </People>
```

I want to be able to display that on an C# ASPX page. 
What would be the best way to go about this? 
I want to display `Person` with `ID = 1` on one page, then press a next button and then it replaces that data with `Person` with `ID = 2`. I have looked into the basics of XML binding with ASP but haven't got much working past `TreeNodeBinding` (which isn't what I need).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mike, did any of these answers help you? If so could you please accept and vote? In this way you'll encourage other developers in participating in these Q&A. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. But, I recommend you to use a `DataGrid` with paging. Give your `XML` as the `DataSource`. Await for sample code.

Ok, here's the code.

In your aspx page create a `GridView` like this. Note that this GridView has a `TemplateField` so that you could format your data with an `HTML` table.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvPeople" AllowPaging="True" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="1" 
            onpageindexchanging="gvPeople_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>                
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>Name: </td><td><%# Eval("Name.FullName") %></td>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Your code behind should look like this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ReadXMLData
{
    public partial class ShowPeople : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadDataFromXML();
            }
        }

        private void LoadDataFromXML()
        {
            // Loads XML data from an external XML file
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(People));
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\People.xml");

            People PeopleList = new People();
            PeopleList = (People)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            textReader.Close();

            gvPeople.DataSource = PeopleList;
            gvPeople.DataBind();
        }

        protected void gvPeople_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // GridView paging 
            gvPeople.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            LoadDataFromXML();
        }
    }
}
```

And, here are the supporting classes that's used to create objects to hold your XML data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ReadXMLData
{
    [Serializable]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("People")]
    public class People : List<Person>
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public Name Name { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            this.Name = new Name();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Name
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
            }
        }

        public Name()
        {
            this.FirstName = string.Empty;
            this.LastName = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.